# Is it possible to use a ABPersonViewController or ABUknownPersonViewController for displaying contact info?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, contacts, abaddressbook

Is it possible to use ABPersonViewController or ABUknownPersonViewController to display contact information within my app.

ie.) you click a button that says "contact info" -> which then loads a ABPersonViewController with static information such as address and phone number etc and would be pushed onto the NavigationController?

The reason i want to use this is the nice functionality which is built in already. -buttons that have address and phone numbers in them that are nicely formatted and when clicked perform phone calls or open the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can use these. Set `ABUnknownPersonViewController.allowsAddingToAddressbook` to `NO` to prevent the user from adding the info to an existing or new contact.